# How can I install gcc-4.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 for aarch

Tags: software-installation, gcc, arm

I've been trying to install `gcc-4.4` (needed for compiling old software I use) on a new system that is running Ubuntu 16.04.  The command `uname -m` gets an answer of `aarch64` since the system has 64-bit ARM CPU cores.  I only have access through ssh (no graphical desktop), but I am able to run commands using sudo (such as `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4`).

Unfortunately, even looking at answers to similar questions in this forum and spending several hours surfing the web for ideas, I cannot manage to install gcc-4.4.  I'm not a sys-admin or Linux expert, so please be gentle.  I want to learn.

Update:

Here's the error message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package gcc-4.4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-4.4' has no installation candidate
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Please what error are you getting when you run `sudo apt-get install gcc`

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update`?